# Valid base64 string for a jpeg

Tags: javascript, image, base64

Is this a valid base64 string of jpeg?

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAgIDAwMDBAYEBAQEBAgGBgUGCQgKCgkICQkKDA8MCgsOCwkJDRENDg8QEBEQCgwSExIQEw8QEBD/2wBDAQMDAwQDBAgEBAgQCwkLEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBD
```

That characters in question are the '/9j/' after the 'base64,'

I'm guessing it could be to do with compression as it's  JPEG.

As when compared to a base64 string of a png, the pattern is different, i.e. the character pattern is different from above.

```
 data:image/png;base64,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
```

The origin of my problem is that i'm base64 encoding an array of canvases into .jpeg's and .png's - the .png's output fine whereas the .jpeg's always output as black boxes.

I'm capturing the images using html2canvas (javascript), they are 'images' of html nodes, I have played around with transparency issues, like setting the background of the dom nodes to white.

All of the jpeg images I am encoding have this '/9j/' pattern, i'm generating them in a loop so it may well be a common property all the images have.

I can't seem to find a decent tool online to validate base64 strings either.

Comment: Have you given the *full* string. There's only 211 characters in there which is not a multiple of four as base64 should be.

Comment: Yes this is the full string, interesting..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's check:

```
$ echo -n '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAgID' | base64 --decode | file -
/dev/stdin: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
```

So it's recognized as a valid JPEG header (this doesn't necessarily mean that the entire JPEG data is valid, though, but at least it *looks* like a JPEG).

The difference between the JPEG data and the PNG data is because the file formats are different. Also, `/` is a valid character in Base64.

Comment: If you do that with the *whole* string, you get `base64: invalid input`.

Comment: @paxdiablo not for me. Or do you mean _including_ the "header" (`data:image/jpeg;base64,`)?

Comment: No, starting at the `/9j`. There's only 211 characters, I seem to recall it had to be a multiple of 3 or 4, with `=` used to pad out.

Comment: @paxdiablo apparently, OS X is fine with it, Linux isn't. Perhaps it's not the full image data that got posted, though.

Answer (score 5):

You can do a js check. Not sure how efficient it will be.

```
function checkImage( str ) {
   var _img = document.createElement( 'img' );
   _img.onerror = function() {
                      reportError(str);
                  }
   _img.src = str;
}

function reportError(str) {
   alert('Invalid image :' + str)
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, I did check in JS with no error, it was the first time i'd written a JS test for the string being valid, so I did accept I could have made an error :)

Comment: You can do `checkImage('data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD...')`, it it's not a valid image, it will alert the same. No action for valid image. You can change it though.

Answer (score 0):

The file type can be identified by magic number. With a  JPEG the magic number is “ff d8 ff” at offset 0. If you encode this to Base64, you'll always get “/9j/”

Answer (score 0):

First we have to specify what is valid:

1. An totally legit image with no errors when gets rendered to image.
2. As long as it can show something visually, ignore the errors.(may have resolution or size issues but we don't care.)

In the first case, we can use  `onerror` to bind events.The function checks if the base64 string can be converted to a `<img>` without any error. It will not only catch all the broken images but also the ones can be displayed but have errors.

```
let checkImage = (str) => {
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = str;
    img.onerror = () => { //do something }
}
```

Or if we just want something can be rendered as image no matter what errors it gives us, we can ignore the errors and directly check if the size of the image is available.

```
let checkImage = (str) => {
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = str;
    img.onload= () => { 
          if(img.width==0 || img.height==0){ //do something} 
    }
}
```