# How an image get converted by base64 algorithm?

Tags: windows, file, image-processing, base64

After I read in **https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64** about how the word `Man` gets converted into `TWFu` by using the **base64 algorithm**, I was wondering how an image get converted by the same algorithm, after all this conversion takes bytes ,divide them into groups of 6 and then looking for their ASCII value.

My question is, how an image becomes a base64-encoded string?
I want an answer that describes the flow from when we save the image in our computer until it becomes a base64-string.

Terms that I hope will be explained in the answer are:
**pixels/dpi/ppi/1bit/8bit/24bit/Mime**.

Comment: I assume the same. 1 ASCII is 1 byte, so as pixel is (in some images types)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it's too broad and unclear. The requested terms have nothing to do with base64 encoding and they are already explained elsewhere. Also, the scope of the question changes too much and too often.

Comment: @ThomasWeller, you should learn from @John Jones how to answer a broad question even if the op is not fully understand the related terms, your comment here is not constructive and redundant.
I consider this sentence `It has no understanding of anything in your pixels/dpi/ppi/1bit/8bit/24bit/Mime list` of Jones as constructive part of the answer.

Comment: You should learn to follow the rules of the site and not ask too broad questions. There was already a good answer, which was then deleted, because you changed the question.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I agree with your point but in Asker's defence, he wasn't sure which (if any) of those elements contributed to the final base64 string or not. It was always going to look too broad.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Base64 isn't an image encoder, it's a byte encoder, important distinction. Whatever you pass it, whether it be a picture, an mp3, or the string "ilikepie" - it takes those *bytes* and generates a text representation of them. It has no understanding of anything in your `pixels/dpi/ppi/1bit/8bit/24bit/Mime` list, that would be the business of the software that reads those original bytes.

Per request `I want an answer that describes the flow from when we save the image in our computer until it's become 64base string.`

**To get to a base64 representation:**

- Open paint and draw a smiley face.
- Save that smiley face as `smile.png`
- Paint uses its *[png encoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header)* to convert the bitmap of pixels into a stream of bytes that it compresses and appends headers to so that when it sees those bytes again it knows how to display them.
- Image is written to disk as series of bytes.
- You run a base64 encoder on `smile.png`.
- base64 reads the bytes from disk at the location `smile.png` refers to and converts their representation and displays the result.

**To display that base64 representation in a browser:**

- browser is handed a [resource encoded with base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), which looks something `data:image/png;base64,blahblah...`
- Browser takes the `image/png` part and knows that the data following it will be the bytes of a png image.
- It then sees `base64,` and knows that the next blob will need to be base64 decoded, before it can then be decoded by its png decoder.
- It converts the base64 string to bytes.
- It passes those bytes to its png decoder.
- It gets a bitmap graphic that it can then display.

Comment: Thanks John, it was a little bit hard to understand how the png encoder works, but I think I got the idea. Very good answer.

Comment: I found the explanation about the dpi/ppi here:
https://sites.google.com/site/dtcsinformation/data-representation/image-representation , if someone is interested..

Answer (score 2):

every image is consists of many pixels, the number of pixel is determined by the image resolution.

**image resolution** - the number of pixels in a row & number of rows.
for example image with resolution of 800x600 has 800 pixels in a row & 600 rows.

every **pixel** has **bit depth** - the number of bits represent pixel.
for example with bit depth of 1 every pixel is represent by one bit and has only 2 options (0 or 1 - black or white).

image can saved in many different formats. the most common are bitmap , jpeg, gif. whatever format is used an image always displayed in computer screens as **bitmap** (uncompressed format). every format is saved differently.

- **jpeg**- is a 24 bit (bit depth) format. when you stored the image it work in compressed form and you loss some of the image data.
- **gif**- up to 8 bit (bit depth) format. a gif image can be optimized by removing some of the colours in its palette. it  is a lossless format.

Answer (score 2):

Just throwing this in for the Bytes clarification :

> - *"The word `MAN` gets converted into `TWFu` by using the base64 algorithm, I was wondering how an image gets converted by the same
>     algorithm, after all this conversion takes Bytes, divide them into
>     groups of 6 and then looking for their ASCII value."*
> - *"My question is, How an image becomes base64 string?"*

*correction :* *MAN* becomes `TUFO`. It is actually *Man* that becomes `TWFu` as you've shown above.

Now onto the clarification...

The byte values (binary numbers) of the image can be represented in [**hex notation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), which makes it possible to process those same bytes as a **string**. Hex has a range from `0` up to `F` which means.. ranging `0` to `9` then it's `A` = `10` up `F` = `15`. Giving 16 possible values.

Hex is also called **Base16**.

- Bytes conversion to Base64 is simply : *Numbers converted from Base16 to Base64*.
- The Hex range of `0 to F` is within Base64 valid chars and so can be written as Base64.

For example :

- The beginning 3 bytes of JPEG format are always `ff d8 ff`
- The same as Base64 is : `/9j/`  ...(see examples at these [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34222108/2057709) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38783884/2057709))

You can test by :

- Open any `.jpg` image in a downloaded **free** Hex Editor. You can also try online Hex editors but most won't *Copy* to clipboard. This [**online HEX viewer**](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hexdump.htm) will allow *Select/Copy* but you have to manually remove all those extra minus `-` in copied hex text (*ie:* use the Find & Replace option in some text editor), or skip/avoid selecting them before any copy/paste.
- Go to this [**Data Converter**](https://conv.darkbyte.ru/) and re-type or copy/paste as many bytes (from starting `FF` up to any *X* amount) into the `[HEX]` box and press `decode` below it. This will show you those bytes as Base64 and even tells you the decimal value of each byte.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload **any** file in a html form using `<input type="file>"` it is transferred to server in the exactly same form as it is stored on your computer or device. Browser doesn't check what file format is and traits it as just block of bytes. For transfer details see [How does HTTP file upload work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659808/how-does-http-file-upload-work)